# Как удалить определенные элементы массива

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток. Есть массив:

```
Array
(
    [34612] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 34612
            [NAME] => Бело-зеленый
            [SORT] => 500
        )

    [34615] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 34615
            [NAME] => Бело-красно-серый
            [SORT] => 500
        )

    [155] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 155
            [NAME] => Бело-красно-синий
            [SORT] => 500
        )

    [161] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 161
            [NAME] => Бело-красно-черный
            [SORT] => 500
        )
)
```

И есть ключи 155 161 они означают, что вот эти элементы массива должны остаться, все остальные удалить нужно. 
Как это правильно организовать?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Пусть `$array` - ваш массив.

Для данного случая самое простое:

```
unset($array[34612]);
unset($array[34615]);
```

Но лучше универсальный вариант, когда вы легко сможете поменять разрешенные ключи, а неразрешенные ключи заранее не известны (их, например, слишком много):

```
$allowed = [155, 161]; //разрешенные ключи
$filtered = array_filter(
    $array,
    function ($key) use ($allowed) {
        return in_array($key, $allowed);
    },
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
); //теперь в массиве $filtered только элементы с разрешенными ключами
```

**Но** флаг `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` был добавлен в PHP версии 5.6. Если вы применяете более раннюю версию, то можете использовать менее гибкий, но даже более удобный вариант:

```
$filtered = array_intersect_key($array, array_flip($allowed));
```

Comment: Пулемет :) То что нужно, спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

в цикле проходим все элементы массива, если ключ этих элементов не 155 и не 161 - удаляем

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if($key != '155' AND $key != '161') {
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//$array - ваш массив 
$result = array(); // новый отфильтрованный массив  

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
         if($key !== 161 &&  $key !== 155) 
         $result[] = $value;
}
```